# How to 'dconf dump' from a specified database file?

Tags: gnome, dconf

How can dconf settings be extracted from "cold" data file(s) rather than the current running system?

`dconf dump ...` presumably extracts data from a cached copy or mmap of `$HOME/.config/dconf/user`.

I want to restore my gnome-terminal profiles from a backup.  The backup contains a copy of $HOME/.config/dconf/user and I want to do the equivalent of `dconf dump /org/gnome/terminal/` but make it read that backed-up file, not the current configuration.